# How to call a bash script function using bash -c

Tags: bash, curl

[Update]Please note that this is a simplified code for this post in order to satisfy [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There will more functions in the script.

I have a Bash script on [a Github repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/awesome/main/test):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fn_test1() {
    echo "starting ..."
    read -rp "Do you want to continue? yes/y or no/n   " PANS
    ans=$(echo "$PANS" | cut -c 1-1 | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]")
    if [[ "$ans" = "Y" ]]; then
        echo "confirmed 1."
    fi
    echo "done"
}

fn_main() {
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        case $1 in
        "test")
            fn_test1
            ;;
        esac
    else
        echo "Something wrong."
        exit 1
    fi
}

fn_main "$@"
```

I want to call the `test` function from this script like this, but it doesn't work:

```
bash -c "$(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/awesome/main/test; test)"
```

The output is:

```
Something wrong.
```

How can I call a function in a bash script?
Is it possible?

Comment: `bash -c "$(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/awesome/main/test)" bash test`. This is not a good practice at all.

Comment: @shin: There is no function `test` in your script (and, BTW, it would be a bad idea to name a function _test_). The only functions in your script ar `fn_test1` and `fn_main`.

Comment: The script is not receiving any parameters

Comment: @user1934428 OP wants to run this script with `test` as the mere positional parameter, and expects `read -rp` in `fn_test1` to work.

Comment: @user1934428 Ah~. Maybe I should remove the main function and just call fn_test1?

Comment: @shin : If oguzismail interpreted your question correctly (but plese clarify this by updating your question), I would simpy store your script into a file (for instance `curl ... >icntoagfn.sh`) and then run it with `bash icntoagfn.sh test`.

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/awesome/main/test > temp1 && bash temp1 test && rm temp1 works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The script is not receiving any parameters.
You can do the following simple method

```sh
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/awesome/main/test

bash test test
```